# Compiler error, with 3.0.101 kernel using gcc 4.9

Tags: linux-kernel, gcc-warning, gcc4.9

Here is the error

fs/fat/dir.c: In function 'fat_dir_empty':
fs/fat/dir.c:124:8: warning: 'de' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
error, forbidden warning: dir.c:124

```
static inline int fat_get_entry(struct inode *dir, loff_t *pos,
            struct buffer_head **bh,
            struct msdos_dir_entry **de)
{
/* Fast stuff first */
if (*bh && *de &&
   (*de - (struct msdos_dir_entry *)(*bh)->b_data) <
            MSDOS_SB(dir->i_sb)->dir_per_block - 1) {
    *pos += sizeof(struct msdos_dir_entry);
    (*de)++;
    return 0;
}
return fat__get_entry(dir, pos, bh, de);
}
```

(*de)++;  is the issue

I don't understand, 3.4 with same coding compiles just fine.  Any help with this would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
After reading, http://lwn.net/Articles/529954/
I was running with -O3 optimization, which effects -Wmaybe-uninitialized

UPDATE 2:
vfat builds as a module, no problem.  Only have issue as a built-in.  I wonder why that would be?

Comment: You posted the excerpt from the code that is not in 3.0.101 as I can see. The patch that modifies it is **f08b4988f229f** (fs/fat: fix all other checkpatch issues in dir.c). Moreover, the issue is not at the line you mentioned. Read carefully what compiler tells you.

Comment: Yes, edited in attempt to fix.  (*de) ++; is line 124, that's where the error message points to?  Or am i wrong,  new to all this.

Comment: Applied commit fat: fix build warning, https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/8c320c079cde0286d71368961231e426539868b4  also fs/fat: fix all other checkpatch issues in dir.c, https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/f08b4988f229fb41a4995829dc0db34c5e35dfbb

Comment: Good addition to the topic http://lwn.net/Articles/529954/

Comment: Funny, cause in current kernel tree.  Line 1279 of fs/fat/dir.c is  struct msdos_dir_entry *uninitialized_var(de);  which is not what Linus patch was but changed to by OGAWA.  https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/5/19/622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patch from Code Aurora Forum fixes this.

From: David Brown 
Date: Sun, 10 Oct 2010 23:34:20 -0700
Subject: [PATCH] FAT: Fix warning

fs/fat/dir.c:43: warning: 'de' may be used uninitialized in this function

The complexity of the code flow makes this seem possible.  Initialize
the value to NULL to eliminate the compiler warning.  This only masks
the warning, since if the value were unused, there would still be a
NULL pointer.

```
Change-Id: I9fc36abace09409853b63e0997328b75ce703769
Signed-off-by: David Brown <davidb@codeaurora.org>
---
 fs/fat/dir.c | 10 +++++-----
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)

diff --git a/fs/fat/dir.c b/fs/fat/dir.c
index 65e174b..409b3ce 100644
--- a/fs/fat/dir.c
+++ b/fs/fat/dir.c
@@ -343,7 +343,7 @@ int fat_search_long(struct inode *inode, const unsigned char *name,
    struct super_block *sb = inode->i_sb;
    struct msdos_sb_info *sbi = MSDOS_SB(sb);
    struct buffer_head *bh = NULL;
-   struct msdos_dir_entry *de;
+   struct msdos_dir_entry *de = NULL;
    struct nls_table *nls_disk = sbi->nls_disk;
    unsigned char nr_slots;
    wchar_t bufuname[14];
@@ -468,7 +468,7 @@ static int __fat_readdir(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp, void *dirent,
    struct super_block *sb = inode->i_sb;
    struct msdos_sb_info *sbi = MSDOS_SB(sb);
    struct buffer_head *bh;
-   struct msdos_dir_entry *de;
+   struct msdos_dir_entry *de = NULL;
    struct nls_table *nls_disk = sbi->nls_disk;
    unsigned char nr_slots;
    wchar_t bufuname[14];
@@ -887,7 +887,7 @@ EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(fat_get_dotdot_entry);
 int fat_dir_empty(struct inode *dir)
 {
    struct buffer_head *bh;
-   struct msdos_dir_entry *de;
+   struct msdos_dir_entry *de = NULL;
    loff_t cpos;
    int result = 0;

@@ -913,7 +913,7 @@ EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(fat_dir_empty);
 int fat_subdirs(struct inode *dir)
 {
    struct buffer_head *bh;
-   struct msdos_dir_entry *de;
+   struct msdos_dir_entry *de = NULL;
    loff_t cpos;
    int count = 0;

@@ -1240,7 +1240,7 @@ int fat_add_entries(struct inode *dir, void *slots, int nr_slots,
    struct super_block *sb = dir->i_sb;
    struct msdos_sb_info *sbi = MSDOS_SB(sb);
    struct buffer_head *bh, *prev, *bhs[3]; /* 32*slots (672bytes) */
-   struct msdos_dir_entry *uninitialized_var(de);
+   struct msdos_dir_entry *de = NULL;
    int err, free_slots, i, nr_bhs;
    loff_t pos, i_pos;

-- 
2.5.0
```